# Can you store presoaked pearl barley

Tags: barley

I soaked an entire bag of pearl barley and only used a cup the day after soaking. I changed the water to clean the starch away and put the pan in the refridgerator, how long can I store the remaining barley for future use?  Should I drain and freeze the soaked barley or cook it all first